# Accessing command line arguments in MASM assembler (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm

I'm writing a program in x86 MASM assembler, and I need access to the command line arguments provided when starting the program. I read on multiple websites that I can access these arguments at the [Program Segment Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) or PSP.

As a test, I tried printing the first character of the provided arguments. My problem is that (depending on how I try to access the PSP) I get the wrong character (or no character at all) in return.

```
...

mov ah, 21h
int 50h

mov ds, dx

mov ah, 0Ah
mov al, offset ds:[81h]
mov bh, 0
mov cx, 1
int 10h

...
```

Is this the right way of accessing the command line arguments? What am I missing? I tried accessing the arguments in a couple of different ways, so I'm sure my problem is caused by a lack of understanding about how to access information at a specific memory address with an offset.

Can someone explain to me how to access the command line arguments at the PSP, or how I can access something at a specific memory location in general?

Answer (score 8):

```
; mov ah, 21h ; Why?
; int 50h     ; There is no such service defined in DOS.
; mov ds, dx  ; Contents of dx is undefined, don't copy it to ds.
```

When a realmode program (EXE or COM) starts, both segment registers DS and ES are loaded with segment address of PSP. Cmdline arguments are available in PSP at offset 81h. So yes, you can load the first character to AL with

```
mov al,ds:[81h]
```

but not with

```
mov al, offset ds:[81h]
```

because you want the **contents** of byte at address DS:[81h] and not its **offset** (the number 81h) to get loaded into AL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I accidentally wrote 50h but meant 51h: the interrupt to return the PSP address in register BX. One problem: when I use your solution, all I get printed is the "¶" character. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure with **INT 51h**? Interrupt List says something different: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-51.htm
When your program has been launched with command 
**YourPgm.com xy**, 
the byte at PSP:81 is a space, byte at PSP:82h is x, byte at PSP:83h is y, byte at PSP:84h is 0Dh (terminating Enter) and byte at PSP:80h has the length of cmdline arguments (03h in this case). You should learn to use debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately, when running **MyProgram xy**, `ds:[81h]` returns the "¶" character, `ds:[82h]` returns nothing and `ds:[83h]` returns the "≡" character, no matter what my command line arguments are.

Comment: Appearently, DS does not point to PSP at the moment when doing **MOV AL,DS:[82h]**. Either save the value of DS obtained when your pgm started, or restore PSP segment address with service GET PSP ADDRESS  
http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2982.htm , i.e.
**MOV AH,51h ; INT 21h ; MOV DS,BX ;**

Comment: I just now saw my problem: I originally wrote `MOV AH, 21h ; INT 51h` when I meant `MOV AH, 51h ; INT 21h`... After fixing this mistake, a new problem surfaced, and I have no idea how to tackle this [problem](http://i.imgur.com/Ygy7ggL.png).

Comment: Just noticed that this error is caused by `mov ds, bx`. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the command line contents http://www.fysnet.net/cmndline.htm